# Using ASP.NET MVC C# and the bootstrap datepicker won't function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

This is the CSHTML code. When placing the same code with scripts in a normal HTML
document it opens/functions, however when using the CSHTML in ASP.NET MVC 
C# gives errors in the browser indicating $() not a function. (Bootstrap datepicker '#birthdate' won't fuction)... 
Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--<link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <link href="~/Scripts/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <!---<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#birthdate").datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                todayHighlight: true,
                clearBtn: true,
                orientation: 'bottom'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>   
<body>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Birthdate:</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='birthdate'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess, it isn't the cause of your problem, but you have `</body>` instead of `<body>` after `</head>`. Just wanted to point that out.

Comment: *Javascript or CSS* code has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC or C#. And the datepicker does work. Did you check the browser's Developer Tools and Console for errors? You may be pointing at the wrong location for jQuery. `$()not a function` means that jQuery, the library that declares this function wasn't loaded

Comment: Thanks having to keep editing stuff for the site to be able to post it, i didn't check that... Do you think that it may have issues with the $ in the javascript?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC uses bootstrap and jQuery out of the box. Create a new ASP.NET MVC project and check how scripts and stylesheets are loaded there. Then copy those tags to your own project. The message means that your script run *before* jQuery had a chance to load and register the `$()` function

Answer (score 0):

Hi here are the steps to fix this issue.

step.1:

lets say this is you _layout.cshtml, arrange scripts like bellow:
[_layout.cshtml]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--<link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <link href="~/Scripts/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker3.standalone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
@RenderBody()
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and now here is the view on which you are using the datetime picker.

theView.cshtml

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Birthdate:</label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='birthdate'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#birthdate").datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                todayHighlight: true,
                clearBtn: true,
                orientation: 'bottom'
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

hope this will work.